# Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings angular 5

Tags: angular, webpack, angular5

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
    at assertArrayOfStrings (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:1620)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:10490)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:10413)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:22806)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:22805)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:22802)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:22780)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js:22740)
```

Normally I'm passing an array of string to Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'Modulo',
  templateUrl: './Moduloo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['Modulo.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

and even if I remove styleUrls it still doesn't work, I have the same code under NG2 That is working wihtout any problem.

I searched on internet for a solution; people are talking about modifying the webpack configuration, but I'm wondering why this problem applies for some components and doesn't apply for others.

Comment: Tried `./Modulo.component.css`?

Comment: @Callat yes tried it without any result :/

Comment: I see `Moduloo` in the template URL. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that too.  Also I know in Angular-6 you cannot have selectors in Pascal case. They must be unique lowercase or kebab-case. Not sure about in Angular-5 though

Comment: @ConnorsFan thats not the problem, thats not the real name of my template I've changed it here.

Comment: @Callat the problem is not with the names, the names I have in the code is as follow : test-paper.component.html and test-paper.component.css

Comment: Have you changed your `angular-cli` or these things?

Comment: What's the error when you `remove styleUrls`? You said in your question that it still doesn't work. If that's the case given that the style parameter is optional the problem is definitely somewhere in your component structure.